# Show the logged in user their account status

Tags: views, users

How do I make a Views block(or by other means) to let the user who is logged in know of their account status i.e. when it is awaiting approval, or was not approved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A user that has not been approved by the admin can not login as far as I know.