# Users who just registered can login & change profile information, but cannot create certain contents until admin lets them

Tags: 7, users

Users who just registered can login & change profile information, but cannot create certain contents until an admin says they can. I know this [can't be achieved](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/187458/show-the-logged-in-user-their-account-status/187470#187470) using the Drupal Approved/Not arppoved scheme. Are there alternatives? Maybe with permissions?

If possible, I would also like to use a block(or other means) to let the logged in user of their status/permissions e.g. they can only change profile info, cannot create certain contents, etc.

Comment: Can you elaborate "until an admin says they can" ?

Comment: I mean what do you mean by "until an admin says" ?

Comment: a.k.a "approved". But if I do it this way, the users can't login & upload certain contents until they are approved by an admin (source: linked post in the question).

Comment: As far as I understood your situation, you have to give "Create Content"  permissions to the authenticated users.

Comment: @SandeshYadav  Good solution. Is there a way/module to make granting permissions easier, instead of having to go to the permissions page & scroll down to change them every time we want to change permissions of a user? (We will have to handover to client, and we have to make it more user-friendly).

Comment: @SandeshYadav Also it is important for our site, that the user knows what permissions they have. How do I achieve this using Views ? Or other ways?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34635/discussion-between-sandesh-yadav-and-p-ng).

Answer (score 0):

As Sandesh suggested, give registered users permission to change their profile information, and remove the permission to create content. When an admin sees that a user is qualified to post content, they will give the user the permission. The permissions will be on an individual basis, so we use the [User Permissions](https://www.drupal.org/project/user_permissions) module.